# Custom geometry in iOS SceneKit tessellation GPU error

Tags: ios, gpu, scenekit, metal, tessellation

I have a custom geometry created in SceneKit which has a GPU error when I add color to the vertices.

```
func costomGeometryFromVertices( ) -> SCNGeometry {

    let vertices:[SCNVector3] = [SCNVector3(x: -0.525731087, y: 0.850650787, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.525731087, y: 0.850650787, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.525731087, y: -0.850650787, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.525731087, y: -0.850650787, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.525731087, z: 0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.525731087, z: 0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.525731087, z: -0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.525731087, z: -0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.850650787, y: 0.0, z: -0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: 0.850650787, y: 0.0, z: 0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: -0.850650787, y: 0.0, z: -0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: -0.850650787, y: 0.0, z: 0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: -0.809017003, y: 0.5, z: 0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: 0.309016973, z: 0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: -0.309016973, y: 0.809017003, z: 0.5), SCNVector3(x: 0.309016973, y: 0.809017003, z: 0.5), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.309016973, y: 0.809017003, z: -0.5), SCNVector3(x: -0.309016973, y: 0.809017003, z: -0.5), SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: 0.309016973, z: -0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: -0.809017003, y: 0.5, z: -0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: -1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.309016973, z: 0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.809017003, y: 0.5, z: 0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: -0.309016973, z: 0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.809017003, y: -0.5, z: -0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: -0.809017003, y: -0.5, z: 0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: -0.309016973, z: -0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.809017003, y: 0.5, z: -0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.309016973, z: -0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.809017003, y: -0.5, z: 0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: -0.309016973, z: 0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.309016973, y: -0.809017003, z: 0.5), SCNVector3(x: -0.309016973, y: -0.809017003, z: 0.5), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.309016973, y: -0.809017003, z: -0.5), SCNVector3(x: 0.309016973, y: -0.809017003, z: -0.5), SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: -0.309016973, z: -0.809017003), SCNVector3(x: 0.809017003, y: -0.5, z: -0.309016973), SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.693780482, y: 0.702046514, z: 0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: -0.587785304, y: 0.688190937, z: 0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: -0.433888555, y: 0.862668455, z: 0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: -0.702046454, y: 0.16062203, z: 0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: -0.688190937, y: 0.425325394, z: 0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: -0.862668455, y: 0.259891927, z: 0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: -0.16062203, y: 0.693780482, z: 0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: -0.425325394, y: 0.587785304, z: 0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: -0.259891927, y: 0.433888555, z: 0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: -0.16245985, y: 0.95105654, z: 0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: -0.273266494, y: 0.961938322, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.16062203, y: 0.693780482, z: 0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.850650787, z: 0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: 0.273266494, y: 0.961938322, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.16245985, y: 0.95105654, z: 0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: 0.433888555, y: 0.862668455, z: 0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: -0.16245985, y: 0.95105654, z: -0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: -0.433888555, y: 0.862668455, z: -0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: 0.433888555, y: 0.862668455, z: -0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: 0.16245985, y: 0.95105654, z: -0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: -0.16062203, y: 0.693780482, z: -0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.850650787, z: -0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: 0.16062203, y: 0.693780482, z: -0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: -0.587785304, y: 0.688190937, z: -0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: -0.693780482, y: 0.702046514, z: -0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: -0.259891927, y: 0.433888555, z: -0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: -0.425325394, y: 0.587785304, z: -0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: -0.862668455, y: 0.259891927, z: -0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: -0.688190937, y: 0.425325394, z: -0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: -0.702046454, y: 0.16062203, z: -0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: -0.850650787, y: 0.525731087, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.961938322, y: 0.0, z: -0.273266494), SCNVector3(x: -0.95105654, y: 0.262865573, z: -0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: -0.95105654, y: 0.262865573, z: 0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: -0.961938322, y: 0.0, z: 0.273266494), SCNVector3(x: 0.587785304, y: 0.688190937, z: 0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: 0.693780482, y: 0.702046514, z: 0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: 0.259891927, y: 0.433888555, z: 0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: 0.425325394, y: 0.587785304, z: 0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: 0.862668455, y: 0.259891927, z: 0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: 0.688190937, y: 0.425325394, z: 0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: 0.702046454, y: 0.16062203, z: 0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: -0.262865573, y: 0.16245985, z: 0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.273266494, z: 0.961938322), SCNVector3(x: -0.702046454, y: -0.16062203, z: 0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: -0.525731087, y: 0.0, z: 0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.273266494, z: 0.961938322), SCNVector3(x: -0.262865573, y: -0.16245985, z: 0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: -0.259891927, y: -0.433888555, z: 0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: -0.95105654, y: -0.262865573, z: 0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: -0.862668455, y: -0.259891927, z: 0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: -0.862668455, y: -0.259891927, z: -0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: -0.95105654, y: -0.262865573, z: -0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: -0.693780482, y: -0.702046514, z: 0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: -0.850650787, y: -0.525731087, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.693780482, y: -0.702046514, z: -0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: -0.525731087, y: 0.0, z: -0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: -0.702046454, y: -0.16062203, z: -0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.273266494, z: -0.961938322), SCNVector3(x: -0.262865573, y: 0.16245985, z: -0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: -0.259891927, y: -0.433888555, z: -0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: -0.262865573, y: -0.16245985, z: -0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.273266494, z: -0.961938322), SCNVector3(x: 0.425325394, y: 0.587785304, z: -0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: 0.259891927, y: 0.433888555, z: -0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: 0.693780482, y: 0.702046514, z: -0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: 0.587785304, y: 0.688190937, z: -0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: 0.702046454, y: 0.16062203, z: -0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: 0.688190937, y: 0.425325394, z: -0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: 0.862668455, y: 0.259891927, z: -0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: 0.693780482, y: -0.702046514, z: 0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: 0.587785304, y: -0.688190937, z: 0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: 0.433888555, y: -0.862668455, z: 0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: 0.702046454, y: -0.16062203, z: 0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: 0.688190937, y: -0.425325394, z: 0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: 0.862668455, y: -0.259891927, z: 0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: 0.16062203, y: -0.693780482, z: 0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.425325394, y: -0.587785304, z: 0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: 0.259891927, y: -0.433888555, z: 0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: 0.16245985, y: -0.95105654, z: 0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: 0.273266494, y: -0.961938322, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.16062203, y: -0.693780482, z: 0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.850650787, z: 0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: -0.273266494, y: -0.961938322, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: -0.16245985, y: -0.95105654, z: 0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: -0.433888555, y: -0.862668455, z: 0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: 0.16245985, y: -0.95105654, z: -0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: 0.433888555, y: -0.862668455, z: -0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: -0.433888555, y: -0.862668455, z: -0.259891927), SCNVector3(x: -0.16245985, y: -0.95105654, z: -0.262865573), SCNVector3(x: 0.16062203, y: -0.693780482, z: -0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.850650787, z: -0.525731087), SCNVector3(x: -0.16062203, y: -0.693780482, z: -0.702046454), SCNVector3(x: 0.587785304, y: -0.688190937, z: -0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: 0.693780482, y: -0.702046514, z: -0.160622045), SCNVector3(x: 0.259891927, y: -0.433888555, z: -0.862668455), SCNVector3(x: 0.425325394, y: -0.587785304, z: -0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: 0.862668455, y: -0.259891927, z: -0.433888555), SCNVector3(x: 0.688190937, y: -0.425325394, z: -0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: 0.702046454, y: -0.16062203, z: -0.693780482), SCNVector3(x: 0.850650787, y: -0.525731087, z: 0.0), SCNVector3(x: 0.961938322, y: 0.0, z: -0.273266494), SCNVector3(x: 0.95105654, y: -0.262865573, z: -0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: 0.95105654, y: -0.262865573, z: 0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: 0.961938322, y: 0.0, z: 0.273266494), SCNVector3(x: 0.262865573, y: -0.16245985, z: 0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: 0.525731087, y: 0.0, z: 0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.262865573, y: 0.16245985, z: 0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: -0.587785304, y: -0.688190937, z: 0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: -0.425325394, y: -0.587785304, z: 0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: -0.688190937, y: -0.425325394, z: 0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: -0.425325394, y: -0.587785304, z: -0.688190937), SCNVector3(x: -0.587785304, y: -0.688190937, z: -0.425325394), SCNVector3(x: -0.688190937, y: -0.425325394, z: -0.587785304), SCNVector3(x: 0.525731087, y: 0.0, z: -0.850650787), SCNVector3(x: 0.262865573, y: -0.16245985, z: -0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: 0.262865573, y: 0.16245985, z: -0.95105654), SCNVector3(x: 0.95105654, y: 0.262865573, z: 0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: 0.95105654, y: 0.262865573, z: -0.16245985), SCNVector3(x: 0.850650787, y: 0.525731087, z: 0.0)]

print("vertices.count \(vertices.count)")
let data = NSData(bytes: vertices, length: MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.size * vertices.count) as Data

let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: data,
                                     semantic: .vertex,
                                     vectorCount: vertices.count,
                                     usesFloatComponents: true,
                                     componentsPerVector: 3,
                                     bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
                                     dataOffset: 0,
                                     dataStride: MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.stride)


var vertexColorsTemp = [SCNVector3]()

for _ in 0..<vertices.count {

    let red = 0.6
    let green = 0.6
    let blue = 0.6
    vertexColorsTemp.append(SCNVector3(red, green, blue))
}

let dataColor = NSData(bytes: vertexColorsTemp, length: MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.size * vertexColorsTemp.count) as Data

let colors = SCNGeometrySource(data: dataColor,
                               semantic: .color,
                               vectorCount: vertexColorsTemp.count,
                               usesFloatComponents: true,
                               componentsPerVector: 3,
                               bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
                               dataOffset: 0,
                               dataStride: MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.stride)


let indices1: [Int32] =
    [ 0, 42, 44, 12, 43, 42, 14, 44, 43, 42, 43, 44, 11, 45, 47, 13, 46, 45, 12, 47, 46, 45, 46, 47, 5, 48, 50, 14, 49, 48, 13, 50, 49, 48, 49, 50, 12, 46, 43, 13, 49, 46, 14, 43, 49, 46, 49, 43, 0, 44, 52, 14, 51, 44, 16, 52, 51, 44, 51, 52, 5, 53, 48, 15, 54, 53, 14, 48, 54, 53, 54, 48, 1, 55, 57, 16, 56, 55, 15, 57, 56, 55, 56, 57, 14, 54, 51, 15, 56, 54, 16, 51, 56, 54, 56, 51, 0, 52, 59, 16, 58, 52, 18, 59, 58, 52, 58, 59, 1, 60, 55, 17, 61, 60, 16, 55, 61, 60, 61, 55, 7, 62, 64, 18, 63, 62, 17, 64, 63, 62, 63, 64, 16, 61, 58, 17, 63, 61, 18, 58, 63, 61, 63, 58, 0, 59, 66, 18, 65, 59, 20, 66, 65, 59, 65, 66, 7, 67, 62, 19, 68, 67, 18, 62, 68, 67, 68, 62, 10, 69, 71, 20, 70, 69, 19, 71, 70, 69, 70, 71, 18, 68, 65, 19, 70, 68, 20, 65, 70, 68, 70, 65, 0, 66, 42, 20, 72, 66, 12, 42, 72, 66, 72, 42, 10, 73, 69, 21, 74, 73, 20, 69, 74, 73, 74, 69, 11, 47, 76, 12, 75, 47, 21, 76, 75, 47, 75, 76, 20, 74, 72, 21, 75, 74, 12, 72, 75, 74, 75, 72, 1, 57, 78, 15, 77, 57, 23, 78, 77, 57, 77, 78, 5, 79, 53, 22, 80, 79, 15, 53, 80, 79, 80, 53, 9, 81, 83, 23, 82, 81, 22, 83, 82, 81, 82, 83, 15, 80, 77, 22, 82, 80, 23, 77, 82, 80, 82, 77, 5, 50, 85, 13, 84, 50, 25, 85, 84, 50, 84, 85, 11, 86, 45, 24, 87, 86, 13, 45, 87, 86, 87, 45, 4, 88, 90, 25, 89, 88, 24, 90, 89, 88, 89, 90, 13, 87, 84, 24, 89, 87, 25, 84, 89, 87, 89, 84, 11, 76, 92, 21, 91, 76, 27, 92, 91, 76, 91, 92, 10, 93, 73, 26, 94, 93, 21, 73, 94, 93, 94, 73, 2, 95, 97, 27, 96, 95, 26, 97, 96, 95, 96, 97, 21, 94, 91, 26, 96, 94, 27, 91, 96, 94, 96, 91, 10, 71, 99, 19, 98, 71, 29, 99, 98, 71, 98, 99, 7, 100, 67, 28, 101, 100, 19, 67, 101, 100, 101, 67, 6, 102, 104, 29, 103, 102, 28, 104, 103, 102, 103, 104, 19, 101, 98, 28, 103, 101, 29, 98, 103, 101, 103, 98, 7, 64, 106, 17, 105, 64, 31, 106, 105, 64, 105, 106, 1, 107, 60, 30, 108, 107, 17, 60, 108, 107, 108, 60, 8, 109, 111, 31, 110, 109, 30, 111, 110, 109, 110, 111, 17, 108, 105, 30, 110, 108, 31, 105, 110, 108, 110, 105, 3, 112, 114, 32, 113, 112, 34, 114, 113, 112, 113, 114, 9, 115, 117, 33, 116, 115, 32, 117, 116, 115, 116, 117, 4, 118, 120, 34, 119, 118, 33, 120, 119, 118, 119, 120, 32, 116, 113, 33, 119, 116, 34, 113, 119, 116, 119, 113, 3, 114, 122, 34, 121, 114, 36, 122, 121, 114, 121, 122, 4, 123, 118, 35, 124, 123, 34, 118, 124, 123, 124, 118, 2, 125, 127, 36, 126, 125, 35, 127, 126, 125, 126, 127, 34, 124, 121, 35, 126, 124, 36, 121, 126, 124, 126, 121, 3, 122, 129, 36, 128, 122, 38, 129, 128, 122, 128, 129, 2, 130, 125, 37, 131, 130, 36, 125, 131, 130, 131, 125, 6, 132, 134, 38, 133, 132, 37, 134, 133, 132, 133, 134, 36, 131, 128, 37, 133, 131, 38, 128, 133, 131, 133, 128, 3, 129, 136, 38, 135, 129, 40, 136, 135, 129, 135, 136, 6, 137, 132, 39, 138, 137, 38, 132, 138, 137, 138, 132, 8, 139, 141, 40, 140, 139, 39, 141, 140, 139, 140, 141, 38, 138, 135, 39, 140, 138, 40, 135, 140, 138, 140, 135, 3, 136, 112, 40, 142, 136, 32, 112, 142, 136, 142, 112, 8, 143, 139, 41, 144, 143, 40, 139, 144, 143, 144, 139, 9, 117, 146, 32, 145, 117, 41, 146, 145, 117, 145, 146, 40, 144, 142, 41, 145, 144, 32, 142, 145, 144, 145, 142, 4, 120, 88, 33, 147, 120, 25, 88, 147, 120, 147, 88, 9, 83, 115, 22, 148, 83, 33, 115, 148, 83, 148, 115, 5, 85, 79, 25, 149, 85, 22, 79, 149, 85, 149, 79, 33, 148, 147, 22, 149, 148, 25, 147, 149, 148, 149, 147, 2, 127, 95, 35, 150, 127, 27, 95, 150, 127, 150, 95, 4, 90, 123, 24, 151, 90, 35, 123, 151, 90, 151, 123, 11, 92, 86, 27, 152, 92, 24, 86, 152, 92, 152, 86, 35, 151, 150, 24, 152, 151, 27, 150, 152, 151, 152, 150, 6, 134, 102, 37, 153, 134, 29, 102, 153, 134, 153, 102, 2, 97, 130, 26, 154, 97, 37, 130, 154, 97, 154, 130, 10, 99, 93, 29, 155, 99, 26, 93, 155, 99, 155, 93, 37, 154, 153, 26, 155, 154, 29, 153, 155, 154, 155, 153, 8, 141, 109, 39, 156, 141, 31, 109, 156, 141, 156, 109, 6, 104, 137, 28, 157, 104, 39, 137, 157, 104, 157, 137, 7, 106, 100, 31, 158, 106, 28, 100, 158, 106, 158, 100, 39, 157, 156, 28, 158, 157, 31, 156, 158, 157, 158, 156, 9, 146, 81, 41, 159, 146, 23, 81, 159, 146, 159, 81, 8, 111, 143, 30, 160, 111, 41, 143, 160, 111, 160, 143, 1, 78, 107, 23, 161, 78, 30, 107, 161, 78, 161, 107, 41, 160, 159, 30, 161, 160, 23, 159, 161, 160, 161, 159]

var indices: [Int32] =
    [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
indices.append(contentsOf: indices1)


let indexData = NSData(bytes: indices, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size * indices.count) as Data

let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData,
                                 primitiveType: .polygon,
                                 primitiveCount: 320,
                                 bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)

return SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource/*, colors*/], elements: [element])
}
```

As is the code works fine when adding tessellation,

```
    let spliqsSubdividedGeometry = costomGeometryFromVertices()
    spliqsNodeSubdivided = SCNNode(geometry: spliqsSubdividedGeometry)
    let tess = SCNGeometryTessellator()
    spliqsNodeSubdivided.geometry?.tessellator = tess
    spliqsNodeSubdivided.geometry?.subdivisionLevel = 1
```

But when I use the color semantic (commented out at the end), there is a repeated GPU error:

```
 Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. 
Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)
```

Where could the problem be / how to approach debugging? There are many examples I have seen working with color and tessellation.

Thanks!